# Перехват кнопки Send из других приложений

Tags: java, android

Я пишу кастомную клавиатуру. Как мне перехватывать события от кнопок Send различных программ, использующих мою клавиатуру как устройство ввода?
Что-то мне подсказывает что нужно использовать какой-то listener.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: любая кнопка в программе может быть кнопкой *Send*. И вы, слава богу, никак не сможете получить к ней доступ. Если бы вы могли, то у вас был бы доступ, например, к логину и паролю, и др. данным пользователя

Comment: Для начала, опишите, как определить ,что это именно кнопка `Send`? Что отличает ее от других?

Comment: Эта кнопка отправляет текст из текстового поля, который был введен моей клавиатурой,  дальше для дальнейшей обработки данным приложением. Такие кнопки есть во всех мессенджерах и, я думаю, они имеют стандартные интерфейсы для отслеживания их действий.

Comment: Эта кнопка отправляет уже ВВЕДЕННЫЙ текст. Она никак не связана с какой-либо клавиатурой и клавиатуре ее перехватывать нет никакой надобности для выполнения кнопкой ее функций. Для чего вам понадобилось ее перехватить в своей клавиатуре, ваша клавиатура сама шлет сообщения, как дополнительная опция к вводу текста?

Comment: Моя клавиатура предлагает слова чтобы пользователь не дописывал, а нажимал на одного из кандидатов и слово автоматически вводилось. Мне нужно очищать эти слова после ввода предложения

Comment: Стандартная Google клавиатура обновляется после нажатия на эту кнопку в Телеграме. А значит, что есть открытые интерфейсы для отслеживания этого.

Comment: Я более чем уверен, что это программа управляет клавиатурой, а не клавиатура программой. Даже более всего вероятно, что при очистке поля ввода (сообщение отправлено) очищается и автоподстановка в клавиатуре. Перехватить нажатие кнопки в сторонней программе никак нельзя, если эта программа не представляет  какой-либо интерфейс для этого, предусмотренный разработчиком сторонней программы (например, шлет интент о нажатии кнопки)

Answer (score 2):

Если вы действительно хотите всего лишь очищать варианты ввода, то вам нужно это делать по событию потери фокуса полем для ввода.
Доступа к интерфейсу стороннего приложиния вы никак не смодете получить. Кроме того, вы никак не узнаете, какая именно из всех кнопок на экране является именно той, что вам нужна.